# What "poetry" is Kano referring to?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In *Mortal Kombat* (2021), an invisible creature opens an attack on Kano, who is chained to the chair:

> Kano: What the fu*k was that?

Sonya tries to kill that creature by knife throwing but one of the knives gets stuck in Kano's leg:

> Kano: That was my knife, too! Fu*king **poetry**.

What "poetry" is Kano referring to?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-poetic-irony

Comment: The classic English poem, “Ode to the Cyborg Leader of the Black Dragon Crime Syndicate’s Leg” by Sir Henry Wadsworth Walton, poet laureate to the Queen, was written in 1783, includes the ironic hook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand it to mean, roughly, that the situation is ironic; as in a gifted poet would have to come up with that kind of story line.

Comment: Aye. it's poetic irony that of all the thrown knives, the one that hit him was his own.

Answer (score -2):

I understand it as sarcasm, a reference to [poetry in motion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poetry%20in%20motion), a term used to refer to a movement which is beautiful and graceful. In this case, Kano is indicating the opposite, that it was a clumsy movement resulting in an accident.

Comment: She hit the monster the first couple of time though.